# Unable to set default TTL per index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, ttl

I have a index (my_index) to which i am adding a default _ttl with the following API as per the documentation [elastic search ttl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-ttl-field.html)

```
PUT my_index {
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "_ttl": {
                "enabled": true,
                "default": "24h"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response i get to this API is as follows

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
            "reason": "index [my_index/a8tTy-UiQ76Z2UkXeJWLIg] already exists",
            "index_uuid": "a8tTy-UiQ76Z2UkXeJWLIg",
            "index": "my_index"
        }],
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [my_index/a8tTy-UiQ76Z2UkXeJWLIg] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "a8tTy-UiQ76Z2UkXeJWLIg",
        "index": "my_index"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Is there any other way to add a TTL to the index for all new incoming documents?

Answer (score 0):

1. Which version of Elasticsearch are you using? You are linking to the docs of 2.0, but the post is tagged with `elasticsearch-5`. TTL has been deprecated in 2.0 and removed in 5.0. Support for Elasticsearch 2.x has also ended recently.
2. I assume you want to enable TTL and set a default value as well. You can dynamically update the default value and I think you can also enable TTL (but disabling it again is not possible). Try the following query (instead of creating the already existing index you want to update the mapping):

   ```
   PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
   {
       "_ttl": {
            "enabled": true,
            "default": "24h"
       }
   }
   ```
3. With the removal of indices you should look into alternatives. Either time-based indices or filtered queries might provide a good alternative.

Comment: If it is unsupported in Elasticsearch 5.0, what is the equivalent in 5.0.

Your code gives the following error
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_ttl : {enabled=true, default=24h}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_ttl : {enabled=true, default=24h}]"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: Yes, if you are on 5.0+ this will not work any more, because TTL has been removed. Look into time-based indices or filtered queries as mentioned in point 3.